# System Vol. Info>FileProtector is using storage

Tags: windows-10, disk-space

I do not believe this is due to shadow copies or restore points as I have no restore points.

[image: File tree photo]

This is on my boot dive meaning I can not update or save anything to it, it's completely full due to this directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to this topic in a different community](https://www.windows10forums.com/threads/system-volume-information-fileprotector-folder.12378/), this folder is created by Acronis True Image

> The offending program has now been identified. The **updated Acronis
>   True Image New Generation app that I installed recently has a feature
>   called Active Protection that identifies any third-party process that
>   tries to encrypt your files and if a file has been encrypted, allows
>   you to recreate it from backups.** The objective is to protect your
>   system from Ransomware. The **app is apparently designed to take up to
>   20% of the C: drive space**, hence my 40GB FileProtection folder. **This
>   significant cost in disk space is not highlighted in the Acronis User
>   Guide.**

and it is used to backup your personal data to make sure if ransomware encrypted your data from your document folders, it can restore all data.

Comment: Thanks, I dont really use true image anymore. Ill try uninstalling it and then using avast to remove remaining files. Ill check in a second. Thanks! :-D